# CloudController does not start if IP of the VM where VCAP is installed is changed

Tags: cloud-foundry

I installed VCAP on a 64 bit Ubuntu 10.04 server VM hosted on EC2. I followed the steps mentioned at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/oss-docs/tree/master/vcap/single_and_multi_node_deployments_with_dev_setup. Please note this is a single node deployment where all CloudFoundry components are deployed on a single instance.

I started and stopped the VCAP and all components were running just as expected including the CloudController.

### ISSUE

I stopped the EC2 instance and then started it again. I then executed the command to start the VCAP. But the status showed as - CloudController stopped and all other components running.

**SOME ADDITIONAL INFO** - Whenever a EC2 instance is restarted both its public and private IP changed. I did some googling and realized that the devsetup script (refere https://github.com/cloudfoundry/oss-docs/tree/master/vcap/single_and_multi_node_deployments_with_dev_setup) hardcodes the IP at various places. Hence when I restart the EC2 instance the IP address changes and VCAP does not start.

I am looking for some info on how I can correct the cached IP?

Thanks,
Ankit

> **ADDING MORE INFO TO THE ORIGINAL POST**

**ORIGINAL IP** 10.142.81.107
**NEW IP AFTER EC2 INSTANCE RESTART** 10.142.159.0

**Executed following commands to point VCAP to the new IP:**
cd ~/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config/
sed -i 's/10.142.81.107/10.142.159.0/g' *.yml

**RESULT** Cloud Controller not started. All other components started.

**CONTENTS OF ~/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/log/cloud_controller.log**
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that  exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "10.142.159.0" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that  exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
/home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:950:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PGError)
        Is the server running on host "10.142.159.0" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:950:in`new'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:950:in `connect'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:246:in`initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:25:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:25:in`postgresql_connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `new_connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:237:in`checkout_new_connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/config/initializers/fiber_connection_pool.rb:42:in `checkout'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/config/initializers/fiber_connection_pool.rb:26:in`connection'
       from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:317:in `retrieve_connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in`retrieve_connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/base.rb:602:in`quoted_table_name'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:275:in `build_select'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:189:in`build_arel'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:149:in `arel'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:169:in`perform_calculation'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:152:in `calculate'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:58:in`count'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/relation.rb:92:in `empty?'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/relation.rb:100:in`any?'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/config/final_stage/check_database.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in`require'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in`load_dependency'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/config/final_stage/activate.rb:6:in`'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in`block in require'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in`require'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/config/environment.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/config.ru:3:in`require'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in`instance_eval'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/config.ru:1:in`new'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in`eval'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/bin/cloud_controller:79:in`'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem is with the PostgreSQL. The config file for PostgreSQL should be changed and then PostgreSQL should be restarted. Detailed steps are mentioned below:

**FIX IN CASE OF IP CHANGE**

```
~/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev stop
cd ~/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config/
sed -i 's/<OLDIP>/<NEWIP>/g' *.yml
vi /etc/postgresql/8.2/main/postgresql.conf # CHANGE THE IP ADDRESS AT THE END
vi /etc/postgresql/9.0/main/postgresql.conf # CHANGE THE IP ADDRESS AT THE END
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 restart
~/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev start
~/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev status
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way around this is to user sed to modify the ip address in all the .yml config files in ~/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config/

For example, to change 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.200 use;

```
sed -i 's/192\.168\.1\.100/192.168.1.200/g' *.yml
```

Remember to restart vcap afterwards too!

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. Details mentioned below:


**ORIGINAL IP** 10.142.81.107


**NEW IP AFTER EC2 INSTANCE RESTART** 10.142.159.0


Executed following commands to point VCAP to the new IP:


cd ~/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config/


sed -i 's/10.142.81.107/10.142.159.0/g' *.yml


**RESULT** Cloud Controller not started. All other components started.

Comment: **CONTENTS OF ~/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/log/cloud_controller.log**

Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that  exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "10.142.159.0" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that  exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
/home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:950:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PGError)
        Is the server running on host "10.142.159.0" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
        from

Comment: **LOG TRACE CONTINUED** from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:950:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:950:in `connect'

Comment: **UPDATED THE ORIGINAL QUESTION WITH COMPLETE LOG TRACE**

Answer (score 2):

You can simply change all local IPs to 0.0.0.0 (including at PostgreSQL config file) by running the follow command at the conf dir

```
sed -i 's/XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX/0\.0\.0\.0/g' *.yml
```